# Angularjs function called in an expression inside ng-repeat is not being called?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angularJS ,i'm trying out an example to cover the basic consepts.
This is a simpel shopping cart example ... I'm trying to call a function in ratings expression that returns the average of all the ratings submited..But the functions is not being called. So why is the function is not being called & is it the correct way to achive this type of fnctionality.

```html
    <div ng-controller="productsController">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>ProductName</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Buy</th>
                <th>Total Sold</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
          
          <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="product in products">
                  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{product.price | currency}}</td>
                  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success"  value="Buy"/></td>
                  <td>{{product.totalSold}}</td>
                  <td>{{product.getRating(product)}}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Here is the js part

```js
(function(){

     var productsModule=angular.module("productsModule",[]);
    
        productsModule.controller("productsController",["$scope",function($scope){
    
        $scope.products=productsObj;
        
        $scope.getRating=function(){
            
            var _rating=0;
            for(var i=0;i<product.ratings.length;i++)
                _rating+=product.ratings[i];
            
            return _rating || "Not Rated";
        };

    
    }]);
    
      /* products object*/
    var productsObj=[
        
        {
            name:"Santoor",
            price:12,
            isAvilable:true,
            images:[],
            ratings:[2.5,3,3.5,3.8],
            totalSold:0
        }
        
        
]
    
    
}());
```

Comment: $scope.products=productsObj; , use this after made changes in productsObj as you want, by doing this you don't need to manage any function from HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got to use

```
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.products.ratings.length;i++)
                _rating+=$scope.products.ratings[i];
```

since product is a scope variable.

also

```
{{product.getRating(product)}}
```

to

```
{{getRating(product)}}
```

Comment: since i'm passing the product as an argument there is no need to refer it  through $scope...instead i can directly use product.ratings.lenght.....anyway  function calling is mybad thanks for that ..@user1386579

Comment: Hi @Ein2012 you have used product instead of products so I want to state that explicitly

Answer (score 2):

You're calling controller function not in right way. It should be

```
<td>{{getRating(product)}}</td>
```

instead

```
<td>{{product.getRating(product)}}</td>
```

Plus you are passing the parameter to controller function and you are not declaring a parameter in function. Your function should like

```
$scope.getRating=function(product){

   var _rating=0;
   for(var i=0;i<product.ratings.length;i++)
        _rating+=product.ratings[i];

        return _rating || "Not Rated";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

change

`{{product.getRating(product)}}`

to

`{{getRating(product)}}`